# Under what condition is a complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ a regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

This is a quick question and I know all about these graphs what I am supposed to know. But I am unable to explain myself in words.
Like I know for regular graph the vertex must have same degree and bipartite graph is a complete bipartite iff it contain all the elements m.n(say)
I am looking for a mathematical explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$, the vertices have degree $m$ or degree $n$ (and both of these degrees are reached). Thus, if you want it to be regular, a sufficient and necessary condition is $n=m$.